# sql delete based on group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have following query:

```
select user_id, trajectory_id, count(trajectory_id) from point group by user_id, trajectory_id
```

It returns following result:
[image]

And I want to delete all records from `point` table where `count` in produced table is < 5.

Right now I have following query, but it is not compiling. What is wrong with it and how can I fix it?

```
delete 
from point
where count(trajectory_id) < 5
GROUP BY user_id, trajectory_id
```

I am using Postgres.

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete p1
from point p1
join
(
  select user_id, trajectory_id 
  from point 
  group by user_id, trajectory_id
  having count(trajectory_id) < 5
) p2 on p1.user_id = p2.user_id
    and p1.trajectory_id = p2.trajectory_id
```

Comment: @Bob: The query's syntax is not allowed in Postgres. Why did you accept this answer?

Comment: delete join is not accepted in Postgresql

Answer (score 4):

I would do this with a simple correlated subquery:

```
delete from point
    where (user_id, trajectory_id) in (select user_id, trajectory_id
                                       from point
                                       group by user_id, trajectory_id
                                       having count(*) < 5
                                      );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax errors to the above accepted answer, the below should do the trick,

```
delete 
from point p1
using
(
  select user_id, trajectory_id 
  from point 
  group by user_id, trajectory_id
  having count(trajectory_id) < 5
) p2 
where p1.user_id = p2.user_id
    and p1.trajectory_id = p2.trajectory_id
```